# Using sed to replace characters between two patterns

Tags: sed

I'd like to replace all the newlines after a line containing a given pattern with a tab.

Input file:

```
$ cat File1
NAME1
N1_info
NAME2
N2_info
```

I'm creating some flags at the ends of the future "tab"s:

```
sed '/^NAME/s/$/\*/g; /^NAME/!{s/^/+/g}' File1.txt > File2.txt

$ cat File2
NAME1*
+N1_info
NAME2*
+N2_info
```

Then I'm removing the characters between the "flags" in order to obtain the wished output. I tried two sed patterns (but none of them change my 'File2'):

```
head File2 | sed -e 's/\(\*\).*\(+\)/\1\t\2/g'
head File2 | sed -n '/\*/,/+/p'
```

This is the what the output should look like:

```
$ cat File3
NAME1   N1_info
NAME2   N2_info
```

Comment: My sed did not behave honoring your post. Please consider editing.

Comment: Try `sed $'/^NAME/{N;s/\\n/\t/;}'`

Comment: Sorry @galegosimpatico, I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is your actual data, then

```
paste - - < File1 > File3
```

is all you need. paste uses a tab as a delimiter by default.

If "N1_info" is actually more than one line, then this isn't your solution. I'd do:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\*\n\+/\t/g' File2 > File3
```

Comment: Wow, that's incredible! It works... hopefully I could condense the real "N1_info" line into one only string (I'll split it later).

Comment: Show us what you really have to work with. We can come up with something easy.

Comment: NAMEn is actually a gene identifier and Nn_info are a list of genome coordinates, basically a *very* long list of strings (but I could process it to a single string before applying the solution you provided). By the way, your method works great (much better than my *silly* idea).

Comment: My thought was that you should not have to pre-process your data at all: thus Stephane and Gnouc have given you better answers.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed '/^NAME/{$!N;s/\n/\t/}' file
NAME1   N1_info
NAME2   N2_info
```